# Error message to user when don't enter a number within a while loop?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a quiz and tell the user to only enter a number, and if they don't, then give them an error message to try again. I understand you need to use something like isdigit, but don't know where it fits in?

Comment: "but don't know where it fits in" ? maybe after you read `answer` ? just an idea...

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    answer = int(input("Enter your answer: "))
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a number!")
    continue
```

Try to convert to integer, and in case a `ValueError` is thrown (it's not a valid int), print your error and restart the loop.

Also, if you give `input` an argument, it prints a prompt for you. It's atypical and not that user-friendly to have them enter input all the way to the left of a blank line in the console.

Comment: This isn't a good solution as `num1` and `num2` will be reevaluated each time the user doesn't input an `int`, which probably is not the intended functionality.

Comment: Then use an inner loop! That doesn't make this answer wrong; it just means there are two options for integrating it into the original code. Note the code in the OP doesn't even include the full loop (as the looping variable is never defined nor incremented), so it's pretty speculative to try to put together a fully integrated example.